# How to type these characters in PDFLatex

Tags: unicode, unicode-math

I want to be able to type the unicode characters of ∫,∘,→,←,×. Specifically, I want to be able to include these into my latex code and have them rendered appropriately on the corresponding pdf. I can't seem to figure this out on my Mac with M1 chip.

Here's an example that I want to make work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4]{article}
\usepackage[outputdir=build,cache=false]{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{lean}
It would be nice to type ∫,∘,→,←,×,!,? in PDF Latex on my M1 Mac with Mac OSX Monterey since I want to use these symbols in Lean with minted.
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Right now I run pdflatex from the terminal like this:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode
```

The -shell-escape is important because of how Minted calls Python. As long as any modification to pdflatex still compiles with this command I can use it. Plus I needed these packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{verbatim, minted}
\usepackage[outputdir=build,cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc, tgcursor, newunicodechar, graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim, graphicx, amsmath, mathtools,  enumerate, hyperref, tcolorbox, sourcecodepro, newunicodechar, textgreek}
```

Someone proposed switching to xelatex but it would be nice to carry my inclusions over in some form.

Comment: It is not going to compile at the moment. But something that fixes it might.

Comment: The →,←,× display, but the integral sign is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{222B}{\ensuremath{\int}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2218}{\ensuremath{\circ}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{lean}
It would be nice to type ∫,∘,→,←,×,!,? in PDF Latex on my M1 Mac with Mac OSX Monterey since I want to use these symbols in Lean with minted.
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```